# Simple script to move files from one location to another

Tags: powershell, scripting

I need help with creating a power-shell script that copies folder recursively from one location to another. Here is how I plan to do it:

1. There will be a list of folders to copy, which are combination of name and ID number.
2. Create an array to store variables.
3. Create a loop that will look for each variables in array and copy the folders to another location.

Here is my code to copy a single folder, but I need to make it more feasible so that it can copy folders depending on variables:

```
$AID = (4069302,4138482)
foreach ($number in $AID ) { 
  Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\sshres19\Desktop\Script\GAEBox" -Recurse -Filter "*$number*" |
    Copy-Item -destination "C:\Users\sshres19\Desktop\Script\Reg"
}
```

The script needs to copy all folders and files within given condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `-Recurse` to your `Copy-Item` will make it copy a folder and it's contents.

Comment: That worked. Is there any way I can store variables in the text file and use it in the powershell?

Comment: Not sure what variables you mean. A simple list of search patterns can be stored in a text file with `set-/get-content`. More complicated objects would require a csv-file and `import-csv`

Comment: Thats just what I needed. Thank you for your help. If I need more help, I will comment later. Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome. You need to post a new question for additional problems as this is not a chat (there's a chat room for that). :-). Also, be sure to search and try yourself first as this question and probably your next has most likely been asked and answered here before.